# ValueError: Couldn't load manifest 'staticfiles.json' (version 1.0)

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I don't know how to handle this problem when I was building an App this error displayed and couldn't fix it yet, could you please help me .

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/abolfazl/socialmedia/core/views.py", line 6, in index
    return render(request, 'index.html')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 106, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 246, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 438, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "/home/abolfazl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/whitenoise/storage.py", line 131, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 373, in __init__
    self.hashed_files = self.load_manifest()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 394, in load_manifest
    raise ValueError("Couldn't load manifest '%s' (version %s)" %
```

I tried a lot of ways that I found on the Internet but couldn't fix it yet :(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The `staticfiles.json` manifest version changed in Django 4.2 (see [commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/afa2e28205fe708334ad463b6d3b0e9960b945a6)).

The error message `Couldn't load manifest 'staticfiles.json' (version 1.0)` is probably happening when Django before version 4.2 tries to parse a manifest made by Django 4.2, for example in the case of downgrading an instance of Django from version 4.2 to version 3.2.

In this case, the easiest solution would be to empty out `STATIC_ROOT` and run `collectstatic` again.

Answer (score 1):

In the staticfiles.json file change the "version": 1.1 to "version":1.0

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django static files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

> Since creating the MD5 hash can be a performance burden to your
> website during runtime, staticfiles will automatically store the
> mapping with hashed names for all processed files in a file called
> staticfiles.json. This happens once when you run the collectstatic
> management command.

So it seems you did not run the collectstatic command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: What does it mean when the command that is generating this error is `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, collectstatic command was raising this.
After a lot of looking around, this worked for me

Remove all the files starting with `staticfiles*` and rebuild your app.

```
sudo rm static/staticfiles*
```